# Qt на windows10, некорректная работа

Tags: qt, qt5

В общем потребовалось запустить проект на другом компьютере , я взял тот же установочный файл и установил на другом компьютере.

---

мой компьютер - виндовс 7 разрядка 64, другой компьютер - виндовс 10 разрядка 64, установочный файл - **qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.10.1.exe**

---

QtCreator прекрасно работает на обоих компьютерах. Компилятор в обоих случаях **mingw53_32** "из коробки".

Но при компиляции проекта которой прекрасно компилиться на моём компьютере, он не скомпилировался на другом компьютере, выкинув ошибку на то что не может найти файл, стороннюю .dll (которую на самом деле прекрасно видит).

По правде говоря даже примеры он не запускает.

Я проверил связи Dependency Walker-ом и получил удручающий результат 
Множество библиотек не было , я докачал часть руками и установил Windows 10 SDK но всё равно все библиотеки не установились.

Вот связи рабочего Qt
[image: Вот связи рабочего Qt]
Вот не рабочий Qt
[image: Вот не рабочий Qt]
Не знаю что я делаю не так и чего не хватает.

Сам не рабочий qt (на windows 10) пустой проект собирает но при запуске сразу аварийно завершается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не понял, не скомпилировался, или не запустился? Qt, или ваша программа?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Не скомпилировался , а примеры запускаются и сразу же разваливаются.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Qt creator прекрасно запускается на двух машинах

Comment: с какой ошибкой падают примеры? какую версию Qt (msvc/mingw/whatever) ставили?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver mingw из установщика